# Regex to find words that contain hyphen MS Office

Tags: regex, ms-word, find, ms-office, wildcard

Regex To find words that contain hyphen in it.

Lets say the sentence is , He is a good-boy dude. I want to select only good-boy alone.The words may be of different patters

1. good-boy
2. good- boy
3. good - boy
4. Good-Boy
5. GOOD-BOY
6. 123-456
7. 1Good-2boy

any character around hifen should be able to found. I tried <*>-<*> its selecting the whole sentence not the two words alone.

Using the regex [a-z]-[a-z] i am able to match d-b in good-boy but not the whole word.

Comment: did you want to match `-f` or `f-` or `-`?

Comment: i want all the combinations

Comment: How are we supposed to differentiate `-` in a word `non-word` or just a hyphen in a sentence `this is weird - should not happen`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the below regex to match words like `good-boy`

```
<[a-z]{1,}-[a-z]{1,}>
```

`[a-z]{1,}` matches any lowercase letter one or more times.

Comment: while going to next word its not going correctly, its first selecting good-boy, then ood-boy then od-boy then d-boy

Comment: i want it to go to next letter say bad-boy which i click next

Comment: You probably want `<` and `>` (word boundary in Word's syntax). I can't see any reasonable way to allow optional space in Word.

Comment: you mean it would be `<[a-z]{1,}-[a-z]{1,}>`

Comment: @praveenrsmart word ah thooki pottutu vara yedhavathu tool like notepad++ la work pannunga.

Comment: ila i am creating macros to do the task inside ms word. so i cannot use any other tool. I could have done it in java just by extracting text ana i might need to check formatting also it will become tedious in java so using vba and creating macros